# stock ticker in ios app

Tags: xcode, yahoo-finance

I want to create a stock ticker from a scrollview that creates imageview subviews showing stock ticker info, and is continuously scrolling. Problem is, I want to get my stock quotes from Yahoo's Finance API, but I have not found information on how to go about using the YQL within xcode. Anyone have a clue about this?

Answer (score 0):

Here a some example with YQL and Yahoo API for XCode on Objective-C.

Try see this codes for some solutions and can use it for own app.

[Yahoo! Social SDK, Objective-C library](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this component](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKTickerViewDemo) for me it was a live saver with tickers.

Comment: this is a little out of date now. They are trying to use iOS 4.1 for it